# Multithread elasticsearch-jdbc

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I seem to be struggling to get data into my Elasticsearch cluster fast enough and it seems the bottleneck is that elasticsearch-jdbc is only utilising 1 cpu.

Is there anyway of configuring it to be multithreaded? I'm not great with Java, so don't know what to tweak on this one.

I'm using elasticsearch 2.3.1-1 and elasticsearch-jdbc 2.3.1.0 on CentOS 7.2 (x64)

Comment: From the [github documentation page](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#parameters): `threadpoolsize - a thread pool size for the scheduled executions for schedule parameter. If set to 1, all jobs will be executed serially. Default is 4.` But, in the [list of default values](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc#overview-about-the-default-parameter-settings) I see `"threadpoolsize" : 1`. I suggest changing that parameter and see if it works better with `4`, for example.

Comment: Tried that, plus it's only for the scheduler - I'm just running a single import.